# Sharepoint regional settings

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've created a Web Part using Visual Studio to show the selected columns of a list in gridview. But the problem is that whenever I'm changing the locale to English-UK (it's by default English-US), unfortunately it as well as the site has no effect on it though the date format is supposed to be changed.

I tried the following code to change the locale and date format:

```
protected void btnClick_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SPSite osite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oweb = osite.OpenWeb())
            {
                if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "English-UK")
                {
                    oweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    oweb.Locale = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
                    oweb.Update();
                }
                else if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "English-US")
                {
                    oweb.Locale = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                    oweb.Update();
                }

                lblmsg.Text = "Region changed successfully";           
            }
        }
    }
```

Webpart code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace SharePointProject100.CustomGridWebpart
{
  [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
  public class CustomGridWebpart : WebPart
  {

    SPGridView grdview = new SPGridView();
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        grdview.ID = "grdview";
        grdview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        this.Controls.Add(grdview);
        using (SPSite osite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = osite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList mylist = web.Lists["EmployeeDetails"];
                BindToGrid(mylist, grdview);
            }
        }
    }

    private void BindToGrid(SPList myList, SPGridView gridView)
    {
        // get all the listitem 
        SPListItemCollection results = myList.Items;

        // create the datatable object
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Employee Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("DOB", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("JoiningDate", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("MembershipExpiryDate", typeof(string));

        // Create rows for each splistitem
        DataRow row;
        foreach (SPListItem result in results)
        {
            row = table.Rows.Add();
            row["Employee Name"] = Convert.ToString(result["Employee Name"]);
            row["DOB"] = Convert.ToString(result["DOB"]);
            row["JoiningDate"] = Convert.ToString(result["JoiningDate"]);
            row["MembershipExpiryDate"] = Convert.ToString(result["MembershipExpiryDate"]);
        }

        // create the bound fields
        SPBoundField boundField;
        boundField = new SPBoundField();
        boundField.HeaderText = "Employee Name";
        boundField.DataField = "Employee Name";
        boundField.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        boundField.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
        gridView.Columns.Add(boundField);

        boundField = new SPBoundField();
        boundField.HeaderText = "DOB";
        boundField.DataField = "DOB";
        boundField.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        boundField.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
        gridView.Columns.Add(boundField);

        boundField = new SPBoundField();
        boundField.HeaderText = "JoiningDate";
        boundField.DataField = "JoiningDate";
        boundField.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        boundField.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
        gridView.Columns.Add(boundField);

        boundField = new SPBoundField();
        boundField.HeaderText = "MembershipExpiryDate";
        boundField.DataField = "MembershipExpiryDate";
        boundField.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        boundField.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
        gridView.Columns.Add(boundField);

        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gridView.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: To change the locale just follow the steps:site actions->site settings->site administration->regional settings

Comment: No,within that particular site it's not working at all.

Comment: Actually we to need solve this program through coding.I tried to do so,but it didn't work.I'm able to change the locale programatically but not the date format.

Comment: The [SPWeb.RegionalSettings property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.regionalsettings.aspx) is **read-only** - you cannot use it to modify anything.

Comment: I'm able to achieve en-GB locale and by default date format for en-UK is dd-mm-yyyy.But it's not working here.

Comment: I've tried my code with other sites.It's working properly there.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx - *For example, using DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern, the date February 1, 2001 can be formatted as 2/1/2001 for the English (United States), "en-US", culture and **01/02/2001 for the English (United Kingdom), "en-GB", culture**.* Can you explain why you think that *default date format for en-UK is `dd-mm-yyyy`*? Can you point any resource that proves it?

Comment: I tried accordingly.But the result remains the same.

Comment: In sharepoint when when you set the locale to English-UK by default it takes dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: As the code was not able to fulfill my requirements I tried that.That particular line was not needed.

Comment: I think the problem I'm facing,is because of the gridview.

Comment: I removed these lines from the code snippet, so nobody else needs to wonder what they do. Do you think that the gridview affects the entire site **or** are the dates displayed correctly everywhere but the gridview?

Comment: It's affecting the entire site.I have tried out my code with another site which don't have any webpart containing a grid view.

Comment: No no,it's a standard webpart which I developed using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Please go through the code.I've a custom list named "EmployeeDetails" within my site.I'm creating a gridview of the list within the custom webpart.

Comment: I can see nothing that could affect date formatting in your code, but why are you creating a custom Web Part? What's wrong with built-in **List View Web Part** or **Content Query Web Part**?

Comment: Actually I was told to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the LocaleID in the web's RegionalSettings is supposed to mark it "dirty" (looking at the disassembled code in ILSpy), but I have not had any luck in then getting it to "update" the other proerties based off that change.